# Error in internal?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with `internal`

```
internal class Book
{
    [Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public int BookName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In another class :

```
public IList<Book> getListBook(int ID)
   {
   IList<Book> lstData = null;
   ...
   return lstData ;
 }
```

If replace `internal` to `public` . It's no problem.
but if set class to `internal` it get error like this :

```
Error 3 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ABC.Book>'
 is less accessible than method 'Project.ClassName.getListBook(int)'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the class from which Book.getListBook() is being called, lie in same namespace as Book?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Book` class is internal but the `getListBook` method is public (and presumably in a public class). Any external library that would want to access this public method would also need to access the `Book` class, but it's internal, and shouldn't be accessible from any external libraries. The compiler error is notifying you of this contradiction.

The solution is either to make `Book` public, which you've already discovered, or to make `getListBook` or its parent class internal. Alternatively, you could make sure the return type of `getListBook` did not reference the internal type by changing it to return an `IList` or a `List<T>` where `T` is a public base class of `Book` or a public interface which `Book` implements.

Answer (score 1):

the exception is self explanatory.

You are asking a public method (getListBook) to return a list of internal object (Book). This is not allowed as internal(visible within the assembly onle) is less accessible than public (visible everywhere), hence the error.

See the details of access modifiers below.

**public**
The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.

**private**
The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

**protected**
The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.

**internal**
The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.